# How to delete several documents by ID in one operation using Elasticsearch Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am building some abstraction functions for my application to call, which will hit elasticsearch through Nest.  One of such functions is a `Delete(string id)` call, which is easy to accomplish.  I have done this as follows:

```
public void Delete(string id)
{
    esClient.Delete(id);
}
```

Now let's say I want to do the same thing, but operate on several documents simultaneously.  My original hunch was to do something like this:

```
public void Delete(IEnumerable<string> ids)
{
    esClient.DeleteMany(ids); // won't compile
}
```

As my comment states, doing this won't compile.  What is the proper way of batch deleting documents by ID in Nest?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To use `esClient.DeleteMany(..)` you have to pass collection of objects to delete.

```
var objectsToDelete = new List<YourType> {.. };
var bulkResponse = client.DeleteMany<YourType>(objectsToDelete);
```

You can get around this by using following code:

```
var ids = new List<string> {"1", "2", "3"};
var bulkResponse = client.DeleteMany<YourType>(ids.Select(x => new YourType { Id = x }));
```

Third option, use bulk delete:

```
var bulkResponse = client.Bulk(new BulkRequest
{
    Operations = ids.Select(x => new BulkDeleteOperation<YourType>(x)).Cast<IBulkOperation>().ToList()
});
```

Comment: How can i specify index and type after this operation ?

Comment: What do you mean? How to specify index and type in `DeleteMany`?

Comment: the client should have the type and the index.

Answer (score 4):

I was working on a .NET client for ElasticSearch 5.x, and I was fortunate to have the following code running (*as well as succeeding all unit tests*) for bulk deletion using ID's:

```
  //IList<string> ids = ...

  var descriptor = new BulkDescriptor();

  foreach (var id in ids.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
    descriptor.Delete<T>(x => x
        .Id(id))
      .Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor);

  var response = await _client.BulkAsync(descriptor);
```